# NSFetchedResultsController not seeing inserts made by extension

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an iOS app structured like this

- **Main Application** (the main iOS app)
- **Intents Extension** (Siri integration)
- **Shared Framework** (shared library for interacting with Core Data. This allows both the main application and the intents extension to use the same Core Data store)

My issue is that when I insert something into Core Data using the **Intents Extension**, it doesn't appear in the **Main Application**'s UITableView until I manually refresh the fetchedResultsController like this:

```
NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>.deleteCache(withName: "myCache")
try? fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
tableView.reloadData()
```

Is there a way to make the fetchedResultsController see the changes without having to manually refresh everything?

---

Note: If I insert something into core data from the Main Application, the fetchedResultsController automatically sees the change and updates the table (like expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To share a database between an app and extension you need to implement Persistent History Tracking. For an introduction see [WWDC 2017 What's New in Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/210/) at 20:49 and for sample code see the documentation [Consuming Relevant Store Changes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/consuming_relevant_store_changes).

The basic idea is to enable the store option `NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey`, observe `NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotification`, upon being notified you should fetch the changes using `NSPersistentHistoryChangeRequest` and then merge into the context using `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` and `transaction.objectIDNotification`. Your `NSFetchedResultsController` will then update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal because the application extension and the main application are not working in the same process.

There are some ways to update the data in the main application

- NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotification
- UserDefaults(suitename:)
- Darwin Notifications

I'm using UserDefaults and refreshAllObjects function for the viewContext.

Example:

```
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName:"your app group name")

    let hasChange = defaults?.bool(forKey: "changes")
    if hasChange ?? false {
        refreshAllObjects()
        defaults?.set(false, forKey: "changes")
    }
    
}
```

refresh all objects function is like this:

```
   viewContext.perform {
        viewContext.stalenessInterval = 0.0
        viewContext.refreshAllObjects()
        viewContext.stalenessInterval = -1
    }
```